# Is there an obligation to be buried in Jewish Cemetary?

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya

The traditional practice is to be buried in a Jewish Cemetary exclusive to Jews. Such as Har Hamenuchos and Har Hazeisim.

Is it an obligation to be buried specifically in a Jewish Cemetary or could one choose to be buried in their back yard?

Assuming all other aspects of Jewish burial is adhered to is this permitted?

Comment: The gerrer rebbe was buried in 48 in the yeshiva grounds and has not yet been moved from there.

Comment: Good morning! Is that written anywhere? He is buried in geulah?

Comment: you're right: "Avraham Mordechai Alter" on @Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Mordechai_Alter?wprov=sfti1

Comment: What do you mean by "obligation"? Are you asking if the dying person should see to it that he won't be buried in a non-Jewish cemetery upon dying? Or that people shouldn't bury a Jew with non-Jews? (If the second option, see Gitin 61a with Rashi and Ran there, plus Y.D. 367:1 and 151:4)

Comment: To see to it to be buried along with other Jews

Comment: I'm sorry I can't source it because I only heard it paraphrased, but a holocaust survivor living in south American wrote to Rav Moshe worried because the place he was living had no Jewish cemetery. Rav Moshe assured him that when he died, wherever he was buried would be the Jewish cemetery. I assume that applies to someone being buried in the backyard too - if there's a single Jew buried there, that's a Jewish cemetery, albeit a small one.

Comment: My late brother served in the US Army and my Father wanted him to have a proper military burial for his honor being that he was nifter young (33 years old.) However he found out that there was no "Jewish section" in the local veterans cemetery. So he of course decided to have him buried in a regular Jewish cemetery. Just sharing the story.

Answer (score 2):

While the traditional custom is worth a lot, I'm not aware of any outright prohibition. There are practical concerns, e.g. keeping Kohanim out of the back yard.

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein writes that we have "Jewish" cemeteries because we try not to bury a non-Jew next to a Jew. (Therefore, if a Jewish family insists on burying a non-Jewish spouse in the Jewish cemetery, if they can put a fence between them or good margins of a few yards, the rabbi is not obligated to "go to war against it" and lose his job.)

Comment: Where can I find this Rav Moshe

Comment: There is also a very important RMF about burying men next to women which is not kept today. @Mefaresh

Comment: See my comment to the question; it appears to me that the Ran (to Gitin 64a) assumed that it is forbidden to bury Jews and non-Jews near each other

Comment: mes mitsva kone m'komo. That sounds that he is buried alone.