# Can a Jew be buried in a non-jewish cemetery

Tags: halacha, funeral-burial-levaya, cemetery-grave

If a Jew, living in a small village, dies, is it allowed from religious point of view that he be buried in the local non-Jewish cemetery?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59781/is-there-an-obligation-to-be-buried-in-jewish-cemetary

Comment: Do you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer?

Answer (score 3):

You should do all efforts to bury a Jew in a proper Jewish cemetery. Should a family quarrelling or similar occur, I have found a [similar case](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/34632) of a Holocaust survivor from the Netherlands, who didn't want to be buried in a Jewish cemetery. Here it is written that Jews should not be buried in the graves of non-Jews (Rashi to [Gittin 61a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=61&format=pdf)):

> **וקוברין מתי נכרים עם מתי ישראל מפני דרכי שלום** - *לא בקברי ישראל אלא מתעסקין בהם אם מצאום*

If such should happen חו"ח, a separate grave should be created instead and it should be separated from the others, for example by leaving at least 8 *amot* distance from the graves of non-Jews (see [Igrot Moshe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=318) to Yoreh Deah 160 - top right in this edition) or by creating an at least 10 *tefachim* high *mechitzah* (Tzitz Eliezer Even Yaakov*).

Since it's a very sensitive and complicated issue, you should definitely ask for a *pesak halakhah* of the local rabbi.

<sup>I would be happy if one could link the related part of Even Yaakov.</sup>

Comment: My grandmother a''h is bured in a non-Jewish cemetery... Away from the other graves... With an unmarked grave.

Comment: @ezra http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1239.htm#15

Answer (score 0):

All efforts should be made to bury a Jew amongst Jews.

R Maurice Lamm writes [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281579/jewish/The-Grave.htm) in his [The Jewish Way in Death and Mourning](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281541/jewish/The-Jewish-Way-in-Death-and-Mourning.htm)

> **It is an ancient Jewish custom to purchase a gravesite during one's
>   lifetime and to own it outright prior to burial.** The Bible states
>   explicitly that Abraham bought a grave for Sarah. Likewise, Joseph was
>   buried in the family plot that his father Jacob had acquired in the
>   city of Shechem. [...]
>
> **It must
>   be located among other Jewish graves, or on grounds bought by a Jewish
>   organization for use as a Jewish cemetery. This has been the custom
>   through the centuries.**
>
> The following are criteria for determining whether a particular
>   cemetery is a proper burial place for Jews:
>
> - **The purchase contract should stipulate that the area of the plot is
>     designed exclusively for Jews.**
> - Burial rights must be permanent. The cemetery corporation should not
>     be permitted to exercise any authority with regard to the removal of
>     the remains from any grave.
> - **All facilities for Jew and non-Jew must be absolutely separate—with
>     separate entrance gates, and with each section fenced completely.**

Similarly R Zalman Goldstein writes [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/367846/jewish/Cemetery-Grave-and-Tombstone.htm) in his [The Jewish Mourner's Companion](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/362514/jewish/The-Jewish-Mourners-Companion.htm)

> **According to Jewish law, a Jew should be buried among Jews. It is
>   forbidden for a Jew to be buried in a mixed- denomination cemetery, or
>   in a cemetery that allows the burial of questionably converted Jews.**

Of course, should this become a real scenario, [ask a rav](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281579/jewish/The-Grave.htm) and don't trust Internet strangers.

Comment: I do not see any basis given by Lamm for his criteria. Are you able to supply any more detail there?